# Property 'run' does not exist on type 'EpicMiddleware<Action<any>, {}, any, Action<any>>'

Tags: typescript, redux-observable

I am encountering this ts error when I am trying to [createEpicMiddleware](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html) dos. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have been working on this since the morning, any help would be appreciated.

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware({
    dependencies: { ... }
});

let middleware: Middleware[] = [];
middleware.push(epicMiddleware);
...

export const configureStore = (initialState: object): Store<IStore> => {
    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    );

    epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

    return store;
};
```

This is the error I am getting,

`Property 'run' does not exist on type 'EpicMiddleware<Action<any>, {}, any, Action<any>>'.`

When I change the type of `epicMiddleware` to `any`, then it throws a runtime error, `You must provide a root Epic to createEpicMiddleware`

P.S. I am using the latest version of `redux-observable` (1.0.0)

Comment: Ever got a workaround. Getting the same issue with redux saga middleware.